# VM automatic installation

Tags: windows-xp, virtual-machine, virtualbox, vmware

I would love to have an idea on how to automatically install a Windows XP virtual machine on Virtualbox/VmWare. Is this feasable via a programming language, for example ? Or maybe an automated script ? I need this to avoid manual installation each time one of my VMs crashes.
I am not asking for a full program that does this, but I just needs technical hints on how to do this, then I will perform your suggestions myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yes it's possible.](https://www.virtualbox.org/sdkref/)

Can't you just make a snapshot to when the VM is working, or at least a "Clean Install" snapshot that saves having to reinstall your OS and common applications every time?

Comment: Can you explain me, please, what do you mean by " make a snapshot to when the VM is working" ?

Comment: [http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#snapshots](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#snapshots)

Very useful!

In simple terms, it saves the state of your machine so you can revert to it at any time :)

Comment: one last question, if I may, can you give me a link to the notion of 'clean install', please ?

Comment: Sure! It isn't anything official, sorry, I didn't know what else to call it. I install my OS on my VM, and all software I commonly use, e.g. Visual Studio, Sublime Text. Then I create a snapshot and call it something similar to "Clean". That way it is very easy to go back to the snapshot if I want to start again, instead of having to reinstall everything manually -- doesn't matter what you do really, just saves time! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to do this via script. Actually, all IaaS cloud companies now try to do the deployment of VMs (and also physical servers) via automation. First of all, it's cheap a quick. And there is little human factor in it.

Not sure about VirtualBox, but if it works with VMware, KVM etc., there is no reason it shouldn't with VB.

As for the script itself, there are big money in this, so finding something may prove difficult. Try to check openStack, AFAIK it should be open source.